# access a linkedlist

Tags: java, data-structures

my program incorporate Binary search tree and a single linked list .
where each operation is done to both data structure .
I have problems in :
1) linking the two data structure , as to have the current for both data structure points to the same element .
2) sorting the nodes 
3) last and most difficult one is to get the performance of the search in linked list log(n) as it's in bst . I can't have the complexity more than that .
my options of using another data structure is none .
btw I'm using java as programming language .

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: So you want something sensible out of dumb specs that you cannot change. Duh? (using a linked list for sorting and searching is just stupid)

Comment: I'm asked to do this , to prove that I understand both data structure and I can solve this trick of linking the both data structure.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) linking the two data structure, as to have the current for both data structure points to the same element.

You can create a tree and a linked list that share elements.  I guess that is what you mean.

> 2) sorting the nodes

You can't sort a tree.  The nodes of a tree are naturally ordered, and if you reorder them on a different comparator, the tree no longer works.

> 3) last and most difficult one is to get the performance of the search in linked list log(n) as it's in bst.

You can't search an unordered list in `O(logN)`.  It is mathematically impossible.  You can search an ordered array (or array list) in `O(logN)`, but that depends on being able to index the array / list in `O(1)` ... which is not possible with a linked list.

---

However ... you could implement a hybrid data structure that is both a tree and a linked list at the same time.  What you would start with a node type that looks something like this:

```
  private class Node <T> {
     private Node<T> next;
     private Node<T> prev;
     private Node<T> left;
     private Node<T> right;
     private T value;
     ...
  }
```

then build the trees using the `left` and `right` fields, and the linked lists using the `next` and `prev` fields.

The list aspect of the data structure could be sorted using one `Comparator`, and the tree aspect of the data structure could be ordered
using a second `Comparator` ... allowing `O(logN)` lookup based on the second `Comparator`'s ordering.

I'm not sure if this matches your requirements (they are not stated clearly) but it is fairly close.

Comment: yes I think it's the most close possible solution , I think I can extend class BSTnode from Node which similar to your , thank you .